# Parse integer from a "td" tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I read many articles about beautifulsoup but still I do not understand. I need an example.

I want to get the value of "PD/DD" which is 1,9.

Here is the source:

```
<div class="table vertical">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>F/K</th>
                <td>A/D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>FD/FAVÖK</th>
                <td>19,7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
    HERE-->    <th>PD/DD</th> 
    HERE-->    <td>1,9</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>FD/Satışlar</th>
                <td>5,1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Yabancı Oranı (%)</th>
                <td>2,43</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Ort Hacim (mn$) 3A/12A</th>
                <td>1,3 / 1,6</td>
            </tr>
```

My code is:

```
a="afyon"

url_bank = "https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/tr-tr/analiz/hisse/sayfalar/sirket-karti.aspx?hisse={}".format(a.upper())

response_bank = requests.get(url_bank)
html_content_bank = response_bank.content
soup_bank = BeautifulSoup(html_content_bank, "html.parser")
b=soup_bank.find_all("div", {"class": "table vertical"})

for i in b:
    children = i.findChildren("td" , recursive=True)


    for child in children:
        l=[]
        l_text = child.text
        l.append(l_text)
        print(l)
```

When i run this code it gives me a list with 1 index.

```
['Afyon Çimento                 ']
['11.04.1990']
['Çimento üretip satmak ve ana faaliyet konusu ile ilgili her türlü yan sanayi kuruluşlarına iştirak etmek.']
['(0216)5547000']
['(0216)6511415']
['Kısıklı Cad. Sarkusyan-Ak İş Merkezi S Blok kat:2 34662 Altunizade - Üsküdar / İstanbul']
['A/D']
['19,7']
['1,9']
['5,1']
['2,43']
['1,3 / 1,6']
['407,0 mnTL']
['395,0 mnTL']
['-']
```

How can I get only PD/DD value. I am expecting something like:

PD/DD : 1,9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference:

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:contains` to target the `th` by its text value then take the [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `td`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a="afyon"
url_bank = "https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/tr-tr/analiz/hisse/sayfalar/sirket-karti.aspx?hisse={}".format(a.upper())
response_bank = requests.get(url_bank)
html_content_bank = response_bank.content
soup_bank = BeautifulSoup(html_content_bank, "html.parser")
print(soup_bank.select_one('th:contains("PD/DD") + td').text)
```

---

You could also use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) for positional matching (3rd row 1st column):

```
soup_bank.select_one('.vertical table:not([class]) tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(1)').text
```

As we are using `select_one`, which returns first match, we can shorten to:

```
soup_bank.select_one('.vertical table:not([class]) tr:nth-of-type(3) td').text
```

If id static

```
soup_bank.select_one('#ctl00_ctl45_g_76ae4504_9743_4791_98df_dce2ca95cc0d tr:nth-of-type(3) td').text
```

---

You already know the `PD/DD` but that could be gained by:

```
soup_bank.select_one('.vertical table:not([class]) tr:nth-of-type(3) th').text
```

If those ids remain static for at least a while then

```
soup_bank.select_one('#ctl00_ctl45_g_76ae4504_9743_4791_98df_dce2ca95cc0d tr:nth-of-type(3) th').text
```